# How to save fragments states to avoid re-creating them

Tags: android, android-fragments, savestate, onsaveinstancestate

I've implemented something like the below picture:

[image]

I have some Tabs and every tab may have some buttons which load some different fragments. In this situation, in **Tab 1**, **Button 1** loads **Fragment 1**, and **Button 2** loads **Fragment 2** and each time the Fragments will be re-created. but I want Buttons to load Fragments just once and avoid re-creating next times.

**Button 1** current onClick:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_root, FragmentOne.newInstance(),"Frag1");
transaction.commit();
```

How can I save fragments states to avoid reloading every time?

---

### EDIT

The **Tab 1** and **Tab 2** Fragments are inside a ViewPager so I could not use ViewPager for **Fragment 1** and **Fragment 2**.

Comment: you can create a view pager without tabs

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

Comment: @AravindV the root fragment that contains Button 1 and Button 2 is inside ViewPager. I don't want to implement a ViewPager inside another ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your tabs with viewpager

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabsNumber - 1); // e.g. send 2 as parameter for 3 tabs
```

and save your tab state

Comment: I used ViewPager to implement my tabs but the root fragment that contains Button 1 and Button 2 is inside ViewPager. I don't want to implement a ViewPager inside another ViewPager.

Comment: when you use viewpager page limit your tab not getting re create so wich Fragment was present in tab 2 remains present

Comment: I think you did not pay enough attention to the picture I shared. Two different fragments inside Tab 1 made the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container_root, FragmentOne.newInstance(),"Frag1");
transaction.addToBackStack("Frag1");
transaction.commit();
```

instead of

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_root, FragmentOne.newInstance(),"Frag1");
transaction.commit();
```

> Problem:

You are trying to replace fragment while adding them via **FragmentTransaction**. If you need to keep instance of them you need to use **transaction.add** method.

> Caution:

Using this method can overlap fragments. So you need to add backgroundcolor to both fragments and make the parent layout as clickable so that you can interact